# Difficulty comparing two arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include<iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
char wordOne[5][9] = { {"elephant"},
                       {"imperial"},
                       {"absolute"},
                       {"absinthe"},
                       {"computer"} };

char hangman[9] = {"********"};

char guess;

int r;
srand( time(0));
r = rand()%5;
wordOne[r];

cout << "Guess the secret eight letter word before you run out of guesses! Go: " << endl;

for (int x = 0; x < 8; ++x)

cout << hangman[x] << endl;
cin >> guess;

while (hangman[0] == '*' || hangman[1] == '*' || hangman[2] == '*' || hangman[3] == '*' || hangman[4] == '*' || hangman[5] == '*' || hangman[6] == '*' || hangman[7] == '*')

{
cout << "Guess the secret eight letter word before you run out of guesses! Go: ";
for(int x = 0; x < 8; ++x)
        cout << hangman[x];
        cout << endl;
        cin >> guess;

    for(int x = 0; x < 8; ++x)
    {
        if (wordOne[hangman[x]][x] == guess)
            {
                hangman[x] = guess;
            }
    }

for(int x = 0; x < 8; ++x)
    cout << hangman[x] << endl;
}

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

For a project, we were asked to create a one dimensional array that only displays asterisks. Then, using a two dimensional array, store 5 different 8 letter words. The program is supposed to select one at random, and then the user would enter random letters trying to guess the word. It's essentially replicating hangman. As letters are guessed, the asterisk is supposed to be replaced by the correct letter. For instance, if the word was elephant and an e was guessed first, the program would then display e*** and so on. I have gotten the program to compile but I'm not able to figure out how to change the code so that asterisks are replaced and the program runs properly. Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: `wordOne[hangman[x]][x]` let's say `x = 1` this would equate in code to `wordOne['*'][1]`. Shouldn't it be `wordOne[r][x] == guess`? Also you should have an array of already guessed letters to check against so that the user can't just keep entering already guessed letters.

Comment: Umm, the `if (wordOne[hangman]...` doesn't look correct. Try `if (wordOne[r][x] == guess)`.

Answer (score 3):

`wordOne[hangman[x]][x]` let's say `x = 1` this would equate in code to `wordOne['*'][1]`. Shouldn't it be `wordOne[r][x] == guess`? I added an `int` to keep track of the amount of guesses and added a check in the while loop to see if the user has guessed the maximum number of times.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char wordOne[5][9] = { {"elephant"},
    {"imperial"},
    {"absolute"},
    {"absinthe"},
    {"computer"} };

    char hangman[9] = {"********"};

    char guess;

    int r;
    srand( time(0));
    r = rand()%5;
    wordOne[r];
    int numGuesses = 10;

    cout << "Guess the secret eight letter word before you run out of guesses! Go: " << endl;

    for (int x = 0; x < 8; ++x)
        {
        cout << hangman[x] << endl;
    }
    while (numGuesses > 0 && (hangman[0] == '*' || hangman[1] == '*' || hangman[2] == '*' || hangman[3] == '*' || hangman[4] == '*' || hangman[5] == '*' || hangman[6] == '*' || hangman[7] == '*'))

    {
        cout << "Guess the secret eight letter word before you run out of guesses! Go: ";


        for(int x = 0; x < 8; ++x)
        {
            cout << hangman[x];
        }

        cout << endl;

        cin >> guess;
        --numGuesses;

        for(int x = 0; x < 8; ++x)
         {
            if (wordOne[r][x] == guess)
            {
                hangman[x] = guess;
            }
        }

        for(int x = 0; x < 8; ++x)
        {
            cout << hangman[x] << endl;
        }
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You enhanced the code but what was the problem in the OP's code and what did you do to solve it?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious oh yea I forgot to add my comment from the OP's question to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Change `wordOne[hangman[x]][x]` to `wordOne[r][x]`.
Also, I'd recommend not printing `endl` in for loops, as it prints each character on a different line.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe how simple of a fix that was. You're awesome.